# Pagination Checkbox

Tags: checkbox, pagination

How to Get all check box in pagination

when I click on this button all the checkboxes should get selected, and when I click again on the same button all the checkboxes should get deselected from all pages.
In my original program there are thousands of records, but at a time 10 records are getting display, but when user click on select it should select all thousands record.